# Power BI - SQL - between dates not working

Tags: sql, powerbi, dateinterval

I have connected Power BI to a datasource and querying it via sql queries in Power BI.

Wants to add a WHERE clause to only include dates for a certain period, e.g. everything that has a date stamp of 30 days from today's date.

In SQL server I would do something like this:

```
WHERE dateColumn > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY);
```

This does not work in Power BI (SQL script).
CURRENT_DATE on its own work - but the last part `(INTERVAL '30' DAY)` does not work.

I have also tried using `BETWEEN date1 and date2` - but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

*** Please do not include suggestions on how to do this in Power BI (DAX etc). I need to work in the sql script in Power BI***

Comment: I think you are confusing your RDBMS: (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY) is not SQL Server syntax.  It works in PostgreSQL and Oracle (and maybe others?).

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, that's ANSI/ISO SQL syntax, supported by some other products as well. Goes well with the <sql> tag!

Comment: @jarlh My point was in the text the OP writes "In SQL server I would do something like this", which clearly isn't right

Comment: It might not be the syntax for SQL server - but hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to achieve in power bi.

Comment: For clarity, if you mean MS SQL Server, write Server with an upper case S. Otherwise it _could_ be read as _any_ SQL server.

Comment: Lets focus on power bi here :)

Comment: If you are using a Native SQL query to retrieve data from a data source, then you need to use the syntax relevant to that particular datasource. What is your datasource?

Answer (score 0):

I assume You are trying to access sql server database via DirectQuery Mode in Power BI. The function you need is GETDATE().

[image: DDELR]

You can design your query like this:

[image: DirectQuery]